# UDP Client C# - No Such Host is Known

Tags: c#, udp, port

I am battling to connect to a website using udpclient. Whenever I connect to localhost, I have no problems. This is the code I am using :'

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();


        udpClient.Connect("www.ituran.com/ituranmobileservice/mobileservice.asmx", 45004); 


        Byte[] btSendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("TESTING");
        udpClient.Send(btSendData, btSendData.Length);

    }

    public void serverThread()
    {
        try
        {
            UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(45004);
            while (true)
            {
                IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                Byte[] btRecieve = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
                string strReturnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(btRecieve);

                Console.WriteLine(RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString() + ":" + strReturnData.ToString());

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("TEST_errorLog.txt", true))
            {
                sw.WriteLine();
                sw.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thdUDPServer = new Thread(new ThreadStart(serverThread));

        thdUDPServer.IsBackground = true;

        thdUDPServer.Start();

    }
```

The people that sent me the URL has confimed five times that the address and port is correct. How can I connect to that address?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: While it might be the right URL your buttonclick event I wouldnt expect to work - udpclient would normally be just the hostname, so I would agree with it saying that string given wouldnt be right. However, to send via UDP to a web server or web server service isnt normal in my experience

Comment: Is that the actual URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the host name to just `www.ituran.com`. There are no paths in UDP - you are just sending packets to a port on a server.

Comment: thanks, at least I don't get an error; but, I do not seem to recieve any information. I am sending the word 'TEST', but it doesn't show in the Output window.

Comment: @Muhammad Ali: Thanks. yes, this is the actual URL. The whole purpose of this is so that I can send and recieve data. This is an external company we are dealing with. This company sends GPS coordinates through that port and that address.